# Using spinner component in quick action lightning modal component not rendered as expected

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, lightning-experience

i've tried using ui:spinner and lightning:spinner in my lightning component. when i enable the spinner the spinner covers the whole top and bottom of my modal page. My expected behavior is to place the spinner inside the modal popup alone. Is there any solution that could satisfy my need?

[image: spinner covvering the whole popup]

Quickaction lightning component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader">
<lightning:spinner></lightning:spinner>
            <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <center><img style="width: 4%; height: 4%" src="/resource/SLDS212/assets/icons/utility/error_60.png" alt="Loading..." />A System Error has Occurred.Please try again later</center>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Please throw some code snippets to the question so its easier to see whats wrong

Comment: @MohithShrivastava i have added the code snippet for your reference. I dint do much in that lightning component.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I did some workaround of fixing the spinner by overriding the class properties.I want this to be applied only to desktops.

```
@media (min-width:1025px) { /*Desktop Break point*/
.THIS.slds-spinner_container {
    top: 16% !important;
    bottom: 16% !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @SaravananBaskar This shouldn't be done as this is not a proper method. Did you try what Junaid has mentioned in his answer? Try adding the spinner element inside modal popup component.

Comment: @SE_User yes the spinner component is inside the lightning modal components. thats the one i tried first. You could see in the code ive pasted in the question.

Answer (score 20):

Adding of "slds-is-relative" class to the parent div solved this issue for me:

```
<div role="dialog" tabindex="-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
            <div class="slds-modal__container " style="width:100%;">
                <div class="slds-modal__header">
                    <h2 class="slds-text-heading--medium">Test</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium slds-is-relative">
                        <div class="slds-spinner_container">
                            <div class="slds-spinner--brand slds-spinner slds-spinner--small" role="alert">
                                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading...</span>
                                <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
                                <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div> ...
```

Comment: THANKS. This helped me fix my non-aura LWC modal, too!
`<lightning-modal-body class="slds-is-relative">`

Answer (score 1):

In my case I want it to take up the entire screen.

[image]

Considering that the modal of the Quick Action has the following css class:

```
.slds-modal__container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 40rem;
    min-width: 20rem;
}
```

We can put the spinner component inside a

```
<!-- Loading wheel -->
<div class="loading_wheel">
    <aura:if isTrue="{! v.loading }">
        <lightning:spinner alternativeText="Loading" size="large" variant="brand"/>
    </aura:if>
</div>
```

and add the following css classes

```
/* -------- LOADING WHEEL --------- */
.THIS .loading_wheel{
  position: fixed;
}
.THIS .slds-spinner_container{
  width: 100vw;
  left: min(-25vw, calc(-50vw + 20rem));
}
```