# Spinner on LWC modal window not rendering as expected

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, quickaction, modal

I have a modal window that is opened when clicking a quick action button on a record. It opens an aura component which contains a LWC containing my UI as well as my logic. A spinner should open in the middle of this LWC component but it is either opening in the middle of the screen (not the component) or it is opening in the right place but seems to open in front of my component with some kind of white background.
I have found the same problem here for aura component but cannot use the solutions in LWC. ([example of similar problem with an aura component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/145503/using-spinner-component-in-quick-action-lightning-modal-component-not-rendered-a))

Here are the different codes I tried and the results I obtained.

```
    <div class="slds-is-relative">
        <div class="slds-modal__header">
            <h4 class="title slds-text-heading--medium" >SAP Contract Validation</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="slds-spinner_container ">
            <div role="status" class="slds-spinner slds-spinner_medium slds-spinner_brand">
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
                <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
                <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

[image]

```
        <div class="slds-modal__header">
            <h4 class="title slds-text-heading--medium" >SAP Contract Validation</h4>
        </div>

        <div class="slds-spinner_container ">
            <div role="status" class="slds-spinner slds-spinner_medium slds-spinner_brand">
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
                <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
                <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]

```
    <div class="slds-modal__header">
        <h4 class="title slds-text-heading--medium" >SAP Contract Validation</h4>
    </div>

    <div class="slds-modal__content slds-is-relative" id="modal-content-id-1">
        <lightning-spinner variant="brand" alternative-text="Loading ..." size="large"></lightning-spinner>
    </div>
```

There is no spinner here
[image]
Testing with the code written in the best answer on the other post I linked

```
    <div class="slds-modal__container " style="width:100%;">
        <div class="slds-modal__header">
            <h2 class="slds-text-heading--medium">Test</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around--medium slds-is-relative">
            <div class="slds-spinner_container">
                <div class="slds-spinner--brand slds-spinner slds-spinner--small" role="alert">
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading...</span>
                    <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
                    <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I see now. Yes, I misunderstood your post. I'll need to test this out and get back to you. I'm deleting the answer for now, as it is not useful for your situation.

Comment: Try setting a height on the container in the first example like so: `<div class="slds-is-relative" style="height: 200px;">`.

Comment: @Sacha: Did you solve this? Please share if you find the answer on how to fix this

Answer (score 1):

[image: Perfectly rendered spinner]

I faced similar issues but managed to create this simple solution that works perfectly. You can change the size of the div as per your requirement.

```
<template if:true={isLoading}>
        <div style="height: 15rem;" class="slds-align_absolute-center">
            <div class="slds-is-relative">
                <div style="position:absolute;">
                    <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading..." variant="brand"></lightning-spinner>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution!  It was straightforward to use

Answer (score 0):

Adding "slds-is-relative" to class of `<lightning-spinner>` was making it relative based on parent lwc in my case. So that spinner was not coming in middle of modal.

But adding slds-is-relative to parent div solved this issue for me

```
<div class="slds-modal__content slds-is-relative">
```

Or you can make .CSS file and add

```
.modalBody{
  position: relative;
}
```

And add it to your html

```
<div class="slds-modal__content modalBody">
```